# In a Python code is it possible to give a color to called functions?

Tags: colors, coloring

As a theme I am using [Dracula](https://draculatheme.com/emacs).

For example I have this example code piece coloring:

[image]

When cursor is on `terminate()` and I typed `M-x customize-face` it is linked to `(default ‘all faces’)`. I am not sure which variable's color should I change.

---

This is example coloring in the `SublimeText` where functions such as: `terminate`, `is_internet_on`, `error`, `session_start_msg` has a different color rather than white. I was wondering is it possible to achive this in `emacs` as well?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know one interesting solution, [emacs-tree-sitter](https://github.com/ubolonton/emacs-tree-sitter) which is the Emacs implementation of the general parser [tree-sitter](https://tree-sitter.github.io/tree-sitter/) used in Atom.

It's quite easy to use and work out of the box, this is how it look the function with the [modus-vivendi](https://gitlab.com/protesilaos/modus-themes) theme:
[image]

As tree-sitter inherit from the font-lock default variables (define by the Dracula theme) for Emacs basic, stuff like the function name (in this case tools), is enough to call customize-face and then font-lock-function-name-face. BUT if you want to change more specific face colour (method,function call) those are define by tree-sitter, there is two main ways to achieve this, with the built in Emacs font customization, or setting the variables manually The first way:

- Get the function at point (where the cursor is) with face-at-point - Call customize-face with the face name (keep in mind that it may scape some characters like the dot), and change the colours clicking in Show all attributes.
- Same as the first one - Use the function face-spec-set for every face you want to change, in this case, the method call face:
  `(face-spec-set 'tree-sitter-hl-face:method\.call '((t (:inherit tree-sitter-hl-face:function\.call :foreground "red"))))`

In this case, I put the face in red color.

For more information, [emacs-tree-sitter documentation](https://ubolonton.github.io/emacs-tree-sitter/)

Comment: What should I do to change the color of functions using `tree-sitter` ?

Comment: Also currently I am using Dracula theme; can these change overwrite into the default theme ?

Comment: As tree-sitter inherit from the font-lock default variables (define by the Dracula theme) for Emacs basic, stuff like the function name (in this case tools), is enough to call customize-face and then font-lock-function-name-face.
BUT if you want to change more specific face color (method,function call) those are define by tree-sitter, there is two main ways to achieve this, with the built in emacs font customization, or setting the variables manually,cont

Comment: The first way:
- Get the function at point (where the cursor is) with face-at-point
- Call customize-face with the face name (keep in mind that it may scape some characters like the dot), and change the colors clicking in Show all attributes 

The second way:
- Same as the first one
- Use the function face-spec-set for every face you want to change, in this case, the mehtod call face:
(face-spec-set 'tree-sitter-hl-face:method\.call '((t (:inherit tree-sitter-hl-face:function\.call :foreground "red"))))

In this case, I put the face in red color.

Comment: You should add these comments as an edit to your answer. Comments can disappear.